# Setting async: false with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any difference between setting:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: '/adminTask/doAction',
    async: false, <<<<<<<<<<<<<<  HERE
    data: parms,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#rdy_msg").text("Completed: " + id);
    },
    error: function () {
        var cdefg = data;
    }
});
```

and:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
});
```

The reason I ask is that I recently posted a question and one person mentioned for me to use ajaxSetup and set async: false.  However I thought it was already set in the code at the top.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that using `ajaxSetup` will affect all AJAX calls, unless you override it in the specific settings for that call.

As you set the `async` property in the specific settings for that call, it won't be affected by the `ajaxSetup` setting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you're right. Only use `ajaxSetup` if you want all future ajax calls to default to it.

Answer (score 0):

`ajaxSetup` makes the settings the default for all futher calls to `ajax`. You won't have to repeat that setting every time you do an AJAX call.

This is documented in [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

> All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that using $.ajaxSetup effects all future ajax calls where as the first example you posted only defines the settings for that one request.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

Answer (score 0):

The first is for that request only, while ajaxSetup affects the defaults of all Ajax calls.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/